# aggregation sum elements in array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some data like that:

```
{id: 1, myData: [[2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]}
{id: 2, myData: [[11, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2]]}
```

I need to sum all numbers in each array to unique total vaule.

Desired output:

```
[{id:1, sumData: 8}
{id:2, sumData: 15}]
```

I tried to fix through group aggregation, but it is not working:

```
{
    $group:
        {
        _id: "$id",
        myDataSum: {
          $sum: "$myData",
        },
      },
}
```

How could I get the sum for all fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `$sum` inside a `$reduce`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      sumData: {$reduce: {
          input: "$myData",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {$add: [
              "$$value",
              {$sum: "$$this"}
          ]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mqkzvVxi6sb)